# Dividing until a certain number is reached and storing how many times the loop divided

Tags: java, loops, math, divide

If you divide 1 by 2, you get 0.5. If you divide it again by 2, you get 0.25. Write a program that calculates and outputs the number of times you have to divide 1 by 2 to get a value less than one ten-thousandth (0.0001).

I have a for loop that should be working but its not returning any results

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double count ;
    for(double i = 1; i<= 0.0001; count++){
            count = i/2;


        System.out.println("You have to divide 1 " + count + "times to get 0.0001");


    }
```

The program runs it just doesn't return anything.

Comment: `i<= 0.0001` already true on first iteration.  Maybe `>=` Hint: still will not work

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
    int count = 0;
    double i = 1;
    while(i >= 0.0001){
            i = i/2;
            count++;
            System.out.println("You have to divide 1 " + count + " times to get 0.0001");
    }
```

**Probably** you only want to print out after the loop

Before the value of count was never being used to evaluate the loop.  Try having two variables.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got it just had to switch some things around
public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int count = 0;
    for (double i = 1; i >= 0.0001; count++ ) {
             i = i / 2;



    }
    System.out.println("You have to divide 1 " + count + " times to get 0.0001");
```

Comment: Note: it can be confusing having a different variable being changed in `for` as the one being initialized and tested.... same for having a `double` called `i` in a `for` loop  (instead of an `int`)

Answer (score 1):

You could use below code .

```
        int count = 0;
        for(double i = 1; i>= 0.0001; ){
                i = i/2;
           count++;

            System.out.println("You have to divide 1 " + count + " times to get " + i);


        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can translate your equation:

```
x / y^n <= z
```

to

```
n >= log(x/z) / log(y)
```

And therefore it's simply:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   System.out.println("You have to divide 1 " + Math.ceil(Math.log(1.0 / 0.0001) / Math.log(2)) + " times by 2 to get 0.0001");
}
```